# How to connect wowza with symfony or php

Tags: symfony1

I am diong a video playing application in symfony.i want to convert the video in to different format while uploading the video in to server. How to connect this video with wowza server to convert the video in to different formats in  symfony framework or php. I am new in symfony. I think you will give a good idea about how is it possible with symfony or php. Also i have some doubts, Is it possible with codeigniter framework?. Why wowza server prefer  symfony framework more than other frame works , to connect with wowza server ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you try searching for Symfony or Code Igniter plugins to connect to Wowza. (which probably don't exist).

If they don't exist, you will have to write it yourself. Which is analyzing what you want to happen when you upload a video, and them implementing it.
So, let's say the video is uploaded to `<your symfony dir>\uploads`, which commands would you have to execute (on the server) to get them in Wowza.

(I have no experience with video hosting on wowza, only retrieving data from a wowza server using the built-in wowza webserver.)

Comment: I'm not the wowza administrator, but only talked to it. But it has a webserver running on port 8086 (I think). So you go to http://<serverip>:8086/serverinfo.  But have you even read the Wowza documentation?